# How to store around 12MB of MP3 files in res/raw folder of my Android 2.3 Project?

Tags: android

I am developing a small application in Android 2.3 using Eclipse 3.4 IDE, I wish to store more than 200 mp3 files in the res/raw folder of my project.
But Wen I started the Android Emulator,it stop working by showing this message in console:

"INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE"

Please tell me a way out from this problem

Answer (score 3):

I think the error is explicit enough. The app is too large in size for the internal storage.
I think it's time to redesign your app. For instance you can download the mp3 file from the network on demand and then save it to the sdcard.

BTW, if you plan to support just Android version > 2.2 you can add `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` into your manifest file and this should rid the problem

Comment: I agree. Such size is safe only on the SD card. However, downloading 200 files is a good sign that you've made a mistake in the app design. Not to mention the cost.

Comment: But this again shows another error and stops the Emulator installation. The error is:INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE.

Comment: Did you enable the sd card support into your  AVD image?

Comment: Nope, Can you tell me how to do that? Another thing is that when I run the same apps in another new AVD it successfully run without any error. I am a bit confused that why did this happened? Please suggest me some ideas on it.

Answer (score 0):

Decreate the bit rate of mp3 files! I think 8bit could be fine if you predict that a user will not listen your mp3s via external speaker.

If you have files that will be listened via external speaker, than decrease bit rate in all files except in those.

If you cannot use any of these actions, then you made a big mistake in an application design.

PS. if it's not a secret, could you tell me what kind of app needs 200 mp3 files?

Comment: Your Answer: This app is an English to Hindi Translator which translates some English statements into Hindi and one can also hear the Hindi statements. So for each Hindi statements I have an mp3 file and when the user clicks on the button the corresponding mp3 file will start playing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use MP3? Android docs suggest you should use OGG where possible.

Comment: What about AMR? Your comment in another answer says the app is an English to Hindi Translator. AMR is designed for compressing speech.

Answer (score 0):

The Installation of this app was failed due to the insufficient storage space available in the Android Emulator.

And this was removed when I run the app in a new Emulator with sufficient amount of memory space available for successful installation of the apps.

Now this app is successfully running in the new Emulator. Thanks for your support.